# Meaning of "dueling weaknesses"

Tags: meaning

On this headline:

> David Leonhardt on the two parties’ huge, dueling weaknesses, as highlighted by a new Times poll.

Source: [Dueling Weaknesses](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/07/11/briefing/midterms-poll-president-biden-rating.html) (NYT)

I found the "dueling weaknesses" a little confusing. Is dueling an adjective describing the nature of the weaknesses? Like dueling being the party's weak spot?

Comment: "Dueling weaknesses" means that the two parties' weaknesses are "dueling" each other

Comment: You have to **read the article** to find out what the weaknesses are. The image is that of a duel between two men.

Comment: In British English, we spell 'duelling' with two Ls.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the text, you'll find the following passages:

> This level of dissatisfaction is a reflection of the huge, dueling weaknesses of the two parties.
> The Democratic Party has two core problems.
> [...]
> Republicans have serious problems of their own.
> [...]
> For now, though, each party’s biggest strength appears to be the weakness of its opponent.

Looking at this context, we can see that it's the weaknesses that do the dueling.

The author says that the election will not be decided by the strength of the respective parties but by their weaknesses. The author uses the **image** of a duel between the weaknesses to present this information in a more interesting way.

Answer (score 0):

"Dueling" is a present participle, a form of a verb that often functions adjectivally. A present participle tells us what its referent is doing, so in this case, the "weaknesses" are "dueling". (Note that "dueling" is being used figuratively here; the weaknesses are not literally engaging in combat.)